# Applying Stoke's Theorem onto Geometric Solids with edges and faces.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, stokes-theorem

In my textbook, a question asks to find the curl $\int\int \nabla \times F \cdot \vec{dS}$ through all faces of a cube sitting on the $xy$ plane but through the base (the base has no face). The clever answer is to realize that the integration of curl on these 5 regions of interest is the same as the line integral ($\int F \cdot \vec{dr}$) around the perimeter of the base. This line integral of the base's perimeter is also equal to the curl through this one face (as if it were there).

1) I cannot convince myself that this boundary "covers" all 5 sides of the square (ie, that the line integral of the boundary equals the integration of curl on the five higher faces). I would think that each of these faces is only describable, with a line integral, using its own perimeter.

[image: Imagine that there were no bottom face]

2) If this is true, I am curious to know whether the curl through any solid with edges (and with one empty face) can be found simply by finding the line integral of the vector field on the empty face's perimeter. For example, can taking the line integral around the pentagon shown in the buckeyball give me the flux through all other faces?

[image]

Comment: (The name is Stokes, not Stoke.)

Comment: You've got a good answer, but in case it's helpful: When you sum the face integrals and replace each by the corresponding boundary integral, each "interior" edge of the polyhedron gets traced twice, once in each direction, so the net contribution of an interior edge is zero. Only the "free" edges contribute, and those are precisely the oriented boundary of the polyhedron.

Comment: Ah, nice point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $\iint_{S} {\rm curl} \> \vec{F} \cdot \vec{n} \> dS = 0$ if $S$ is a closed surface. So, the flux of curl($\vec{F}$) through all the faces except the base should be equal to the negative of the curl of $\vec{F}$ through the base, making sure that you parametrize the base with the normal vector pointing downwards.

So, we have $\iint_{S'} {\rm curl} \> \vec{F} \cdot \vec{n} \> dS = -\iint_{B} {\rm curl} \> \vec{F} \cdot \vec{n} \> dS$, where $S'$ are the non-base faces and $B$ is the base. This is probably easier to compute than a line integral since the normal vector is just $(0, 0, -1)$.

To see that it is in fact equal to the line integral around the base, recall that Stokes' Theorem requires the surface and the boundary to be piecewise-smooth, which they are.

Comment: Sometimes, it helps to understand why certain setups DONT work. if I had chosen my boundary to be composed of one of the base's edge, two halves of the two edges, and an imaginary line I drew across, why wouldn't that work?

Comment: Effectively, why can't the boundary be half of the base? A rectangle with two edges the length of the square and two edge half the length of the square.

Comment: @Muno You can use any closed curve to divide the surface into 2 regions and apply the same strategy.